# MVC Create my own membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

Often when I use the simple membership provider I find myself limited.
So I've decided to create my own membership provider, but I'm abit lost..

What i've done so far:

1. Created a new class
   public class CustomMembershipProvider : System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider..
2. Changed my Web.config file so i can use my own provider..
3. I can now access these functions in my controller like this:
   var membership = (Testproject.Custom_Membership_Provider.CustomMembershipProvider)System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider;

What's next?
I would like to be able to retrieve data from my database and change it. For example, get current user email and be able to change it.

Am I on the right track here? Could you give me some starter help on those two functions?

Also.. If you don't use any of the membership providers, custom or simple, how are you suppose to retrieve and change data from database? Could you give me a example on that? Like, retrieve current user and change it's email.

I appreciate all the help i can get! Thank you,
/confused kiddo

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft gave up on the simple membership provider and introduced new one - check [ASP.Net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)
Here you have some articles about customizing it:

[Customizing profile information in ASP.NET Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx)

[Customizing ASP.NET Identity in MVC 5](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.ch/2013/10/customizing-aspnet-identity-in-mvc-5.html)

Check this one as well:

[The good, the bad and the ugly of ASP.NET Identity](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/20/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-of-asp-net-identity/)

I hope it will be useful.

Comment: Not the kind of answer i was looking for but thank you, i did not know that:)

Answer (score 0):

```
What's next?
```

Implement methods that you need. Like If you need to be able to retrieve user information, implement

> MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline);

```
Am I on the right track here?
```

Well that depends on question why you choose to roll out your own provider? Example you share can be satisfied with `SimpleMembershipProvider` as well. For example, if you want to add email for a user, you can add it into UserProfile table and easily retrieve it. See example [here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html)

```
Could you give me some starter help on those two functions?
```

You need to basically implement CRUD operation with database (SQL Server) and ORM (e.g. EF) of your choice. Once you have the ability to read and write from a table in database, create a table UserProfile. When user register, insert user information into it. When you want to validate, call `ValidateUser()` method. Since you are deriving from `MembershipProvider`, you will have to implement all required methods. For more information refer this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers)

```
If you don't use any of the membership providers, custom or simple, how are you suppose to retrieve and change data from database?
```

There are two concerns in discussion here, one ability to validate a user (User Authentication), second ability to store and retrieve the data from database. I believe your question is with reference to first.

ASP.NET implements authentication through authentication providers, the code modules that contain the code necessary to authenticate the requestor's credentials. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.ASPX)

If you do not want to use ASP.NET membership, you will have to choose another framework for user authentication or roll your own (definitely not a cost effective way).